# Downloading ZIP content through REST API call in Powershell

Tags: rest, powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

This  is a sample REST API uri to retrieve logs from the AzureDevOps Release. 
 `https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}/logs?api-version=4.1-preview.2`

The Verb is GET and content type is "application/zip"

How do i retrieve the zip file  through a REST API call through powershell  using `Invoke-RestMethod` ?

If i pass `Out-File` to this command and save it as zip, it doesn't convert the  binary output of the API response to zip.

How do i do it ?

Comment: What is the binary output of the API?  Is it a hexadecimal string or a byte array?  Is it base64 encoded?  The idea is that you'll need to take whatever the response is, turn it into a byte array, and send it to `Set-Content -Encoding byte` or `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($FullPathToOutputFile, $ByteArray)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to name the output as zip.

Below Powershell script works for me:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}",
   [string]$project = "0522TFVCScrum",
   [string]$releaseid = "35",
   [string]$filename = "D:\temp\ReleaseLogs_$releaseid.zip",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password/PAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uri = "$collectionUrl/$project/_apis/Release/releases/$releaseid/logs"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/zip" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -OutFile $filename
```

Comment: Works Perfectly. I was using the `| Out-File -filepath C:\Test1\logs.zip' which didn't work. thank a ton!